# Rails 6 - sidekiq doesn't dequeue on development

Tags: redis, sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-6

I've had this problem on development : Sidekiq enqueues the job, but never dequeues. On Production (Heroku), everything works fine. Here's a tiny part of the launching messages on my terminal :

```
2020-06-16T17:39:20.481Z pid=7317 tid=oxx33ap5d INFO: Booted Rails 6.0.2.1 application in development environment
2020-06-16T17:39:20.481Z pid=7317 tid=oxx33ap5d INFO: Running in ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-darwin16]
2020-06-16T17:39:20.481Z pid=7317 tid=oxx33ap5d INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
2020-06-16T17:39:20.482Z pid=7317 tid=oxx33ap5d INFO: Upgrade to Sidekiq Pro for more features and support: http://sidekiq.org
2020-06-16T17:39:20.482Z pid=7317 tid=oxx33ap5d INFO: Booting Sidekiq 6.0.6 with redis options {:id=>"Sidekiq-server-PID-7317", :url=>nil}
2020-06-16T17:39:20.536Z pid=7317 tid=oxx33ap5d DEBUG: Client Middleware: 
2020-06-16T17:39:20.536Z pid=7317 tid=oxx33ap5d DEBUG: Server Middleware: Sidekiq::Failures::Middleware
2020-06-16T17:39:20.536Z pid=7317 tid=oxx33ap5d INFO: Starting processing, hit Ctrl-C to stop
2020-06-16T17:39:20.536Z pid=7317 tid=oxx33ap5d DEBUG: {:queues=>["default", "mailers"], :labels=>[], :concurrency=>3, :require=>".", :environment=>nil, :timeout=>240, :poll_interval_average=>nil, :average_scheduled_poll_interval=>5, :error_handlers=>[#<Sidekiq::ExceptionHandler::Logger:0x00007ffe1b158260>], :death_handlers=>[], :lifecycle_events=>{:startup=>[], :quiet=>[], :shutdown=>[], :heartbeat=>[]}, :dead_max_jobs=>10000, :dead_timeout_in_seconds=>15552000, :reloader=>#<Sidekiq::Rails::Reloader @app=Wadzatsong::Application>, :verbose=>true, :config_file=>"./config/sidekiq.yml", :strict=>true, :tag=>"wadzatsong", :identity=>"MBP-de-apple:7317:18f040a5293c"}
2020-06-16T17:39:20.586Z pid=7317 tid=oxx3b6ag9 class=PlaylistJob jid=9fda5f6075587921f5d3be51 INFO: start
2020-06-16T17:39:20.586Z pid=7317 tid=oxx3b6aid class=PlaylistJob jid=d1b5536379c0a65ec73381f6 INFO: start
2020-06-16T17:39:20.586Z pid=7317 tid=oxx3b6ac1 class=PlaylistJob jid=122c610b9d44942d06652289 INFO: start
2020-06-16T17:39:27.001Z pid=7317 tid=oxx3b6ac1 class=PlaylistJob jid=122c610b9d44942d06652289 elapsed=6.415 INFO: fail
2020-06-16T17:39:27.001Z pid=7317 tid=oxx3b6ac1 WARN: {"context":"Job raised exception","job":{"retry":true,"queue":"default","class":"ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter::JobWrapper","wrapped":"PlaylistJob","args":[{"job_class":"PlaylistJob","job_id":"aa761c60-ead2-44a6-b5ab-41559a595143","provider_job_id":null,"queue_name":"default","priority":null,"arguments":["French"],"executions":0,"exception_executions":{},"locale":"en","timezone":"UTC","enqueued_at":"2020-06-15T17:31:35Z"}],"jid":"122c610b9d44942d06652289","created_at":1592242295.783063,"enqueued_at":1592242295.783238,"error_message":"429 Too Many Requests","error_class":"RestClient::TooManyRequests","processor":"MBP-de-apple:7317","failed_at":1592329166.999786},"jobstr":"{\"retry\":true,\"queue\":\"default\",\"class\":\"ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter::JobWrapper\",\"wrapped\":\"PlaylistJob\",\"args\":[{\"job_class\":\"PlaylistJob\",\"job_id\":\"aa761c60-ead2-44a6-b5ab-41559a595143\",\"provider_job_id\":null,\"queue_name\":\"default\",\"priority\":null,\"arguments\":[\"French\"],\"executions\":0,\"exception_executions\":{},\"locale\":\"en\",\"timezone\":\"UTC\",\"enqueued_at\":\"2020-06-15T17:31:35Z\"}],\"jid\":\"122c610b9d44942d06652289\",\"created_at\":1592242295.783063,\"enqueued_at\":1592242295.783238}"}
2020-06-16T17:39:27.002Z pid=7317 tid=oxx3b6ac1 WARN: RestClient::TooManyRequests: 429 Too Many Requests
2020-06-16T17:39:27.002Z pid=7317 tid=oxx3b6ac1 WARN: /Users/pierre/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.2/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:223:in `exception_with_response'
/Users/pierre/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.2/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:103:in `return!'
/Users/pierre/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.2/lib/restclient/request.rb:809:in `process_result'
/Users/pierre/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rest-client-2.0.2/lib/restclient/request.rb:725:in `block in transmit'
/Users/pierre/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/2.6.0/net/http.rb:920:in `start'
```

All the setup seems correct, since it's worked fine on heroku :

```
config/application.rb
   [...]
    config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
```

sidekiq.yml

```
:concurrency: 3
:timeout: 240
:verbose: true
:queues:  # Queue priority: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options
  - default
  - mailers
```

routes.rb

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
    # Sidekiq Web UI, only for admins.
    require "sidekiq/web"
    authenticate :user, lambda { |u| u.admin } do
      mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
    end
  end
```

my job :

```
class PlaylistJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(name)
        [...]
   end
end
```

and my http://localhost:3000/sidekiq shows the following. I failed the 204 manually, but the 11 retries never succeed

```
215 Processed
204 Failed
0 Busy
0 Enqueued
11 Retries
0 Scheduled
0 Dead
```

This setup of Sidekiq for Redis is here
**initializers/redis.rb** :

```
$redis = Redis.new

url = ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"]

if url
  Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
    config.redis = { url: url }
  end

  Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    config.redis = { url: url }
  end
  $redis = Redis.new(:url => url)
end
```

Comment: `Booting Sidekiq 6.0.6 with redis options {:id=>"Sidekiq-server-PID-7317", :url=>nil}` redis url nil is strange. What is your Sidekiq setup for your local redis?

Comment: Well, that's the point. This setup is here in **redis.rb** :                                                             ```$redis = Redis.new

url = ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"]

if url
  Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
    config.redis = { url: url }
  end

  Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    config.redis = { url: url }
  end
  $redis = Redis.new(:url => url)
end```

Comment: Have you got defined `ENV['REDISCLOUD_URL']` in your local environment? Do you have a `.env`file with a value for this variable in your root folder? If not try replacing your url variable for something like this: `url = "redis://localhost:6379/0"`or `url = "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0"` and be sure that in your command console `$ redis-cli ping` responds with `PONG`. If works, you should create an `if` in your `redis.rb` config file. If `Rails.env == "production"` you should use your `ENV['REDISCLOUD_URL']` else you should use the local redis url.

Comment: Yes I have difined in .env

Comment: I have defined in my **.env** ```REDISCLOUD_URL=redis://rediscloud:CViJZ... ```, and it still doesn't work. ```redis-cli ping ```gives a ```PONG ```, I tried the different urls but no way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out and fixed it, thanx to cmramseyer's comment, hope I will help with my conclusions here :

The setup of Sidekiq for Redis is here
**initializers/redis.rb** :

```
$redis = Redis.new

url = ENV["REDISCLOUD_URL"]

if url
  Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
    config.redis = { url: url }
  end

  Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    config.redis = { url: url }
  end
  $redis = Redis.new(:url => url)
end
```

I changed the local url, as indicated by cmramseyer, to

```
url = "redis://localhost:6379/0"
```

Actually, the url channel already in use on production is redis://localhost:6379/1, so I updated this url to match `"redis://localhost:6379/1"`. 0 or 1, important is all the URLs match !

My development configuration in **initializers/cable.yml** was set to development: async ! so I updated it to match the same url as previous .

```
development:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDISCLOUD_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>
  channel_prefix: _wadzatsong_development

test:
  adapter: test

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDISCLOUD_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>
  channel_prefix: _wadzatsong_production
```

That's all folks !

Comment: Awesome! Remember always to config your services by environments and using environment variables. If Rails.env.development? TheService.config = ENV['THE_SERVICE_VAR_DEV'] elsif Rails.env.production? TheService.config = ENV['THE_SERVICE_VAR_PROD'] end. You know, that's a good practice and you are going to have all your config variables in one place (.env file).

Comment: Yes @cmramseyer , I copied your idiomatic config to process it in my config ^^